# Visa start date

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, schengen

I am applying for a short term tourist Schengen visa. The flight I booked is leaving my home country Thursday  evening and arriving Friday morning. My hotel is reserved from Friday, as I am on the plane Thursday night.

Should I ask for my visa to start on Thursday or Friday? I am leaning towards asking for Thursday but worried consulate will be concerned I don’t have a hotel for Thursday…

Would having it start on Friday be an issue with boarding the plane? Or would Thursday be an issue with the embassy? Thank you!